# Jquery, change the textArea size

Tags: jquery, textarea

I wanna change the textAreaSize:
when I click on the text area, I have to show all the text.
when I leave it, the height must return to its default value.

statically, I did like that:

```
function resizeMyTextArea(){
$('#myTextArea').css("height",120);
}
```

sometimes I need more than 120 to show all the text, how can I do that dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a quite simple way to achieve this: you have to add the textarea content to a div, which is offset from your page (by CSS). Then you get the height of the div and apply it onto your textarea. What is important to do, is to replace the textarea's line breaks into `<br>` tags, which you can achieve with a simple replace(), here is the code:

```
$('#myTextArea').on('click', function(){
    orig_h=$(this).height()
    html=$('#myTextArea').val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
    $('#myoffthepageTextArea').html(html);
    h=$('#myoffthepageTextArea').height()
    $('#myTextArea').height(h)
}).on('blur', function(){
    $('#myTextArea').height(orig_h)    
});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K4qEA/2/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following jQuery plugin

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();   
});
```

you can write additional code for `blur` event on the textarea that restores the text area size to default. Based on the documentation than can be done using (Please test the code in your system, I haven't tried this in my system but I am sure that it'll work) :

```
$('textarea.example').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).autosize();
});

$('textarea.example').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).trigger('autosize.destroy');

});
```

Comment: I work on an old project, autosize doesn t work in my case :(

Comment: what do you mean by old project. This plugin is compatible with: jQuery 1.7+ in Chrome, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, Internet Explorer 6+, Opera 11+. IE 6+ !!! what else can one expect :D

Comment: I use FF 28.0 and I get this error: TypeError: $(...).autosize is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I did like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var orig_h;
    jQuery("#myTextArea").on("focus", function(){
       orig_h=jQuery(this).height();
       jQuery(this).height( jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight );
    }).on('blur', function(){
        jQuery('#myTextArea').height(orig_h)    
    });
});
```